# create XP usb boot disk in Vista

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, usb, boot, usb-flash-drive

My netbook (running on XP) recently encountered "NTLDR is missing" problem. However, since I don't have an external dvd, I need to create a USB boot-up disk to re-install XP. Unfortunately, my other laptop is running Vista.

Is it possible to create a USB boot-up disk using Vista?

Thanks,
Erwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/)** to prepare a bootable USB drive from any Windows installation disk.

Answer (score 0):

It's perhaps easier to take a portable Linux distro ([tutorials can be found here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/)) and [follow these steps from Arsgeek.com](http://www.noob2geek.com/windows-tutorials/how-to-fix-ntldr-missing-error-in-windows-xp/)

> Boot into your Ubuntu LiveCD on the
>   offending machine. Once Ubuntu starts
>   up, go to System -> Administration ->
>   Software Sources and enable (by
>   checking it off) the Universal
>   repository.
>
> Now, open a terminal session
>   (Applications -> Accessories ->
>   Terminal) and type the following:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install ms-sys
> ```
>
> ms-sys is a program used to write
>   Microsoft compatible boot records. Now
>   you’ll need to figure out what
>   partition is the one hosting your
>   Windows operating system. Back in the
>   command line, type:
>
> ```
> sudo fdisk -l
> ```
>
> That will list the available
>   partitions. You’re looking for a
>   partition that says something like
>
> ```
> /dev/sda1 1 9327 74919096 83 NTFS
> ```
>
> The two important bits are the
>   ‘/dev/sda1‘ which is the partition
>   itself and the ‘NTFS‘ which tells us
>   it’s a Windows formatted partition. 
>   So your Windows partition exists on
>   your drive sda and it’s partition 1.
>   The MBR for drive sda (assuming you
>   boot into windows using it’s native
>   boot loader) is what you want to
>   repair. We want to fix the MBR on
>   /dev/sda. To do so, type:
>
> ```
> sudo ms-sys -m /dev/sda
> ```
>
> You’ll want to change the ’sda’ bit if
>   your results from ‘fdisk -l‘ are
>   different.  If for instance your
>   windows install is on sdb or hda. Once
>   you do that, reboot the machine,
>   removing the LiveCD from the drive and
>   Windows should come back to you.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the instructions. I wasn't able to do it, though, since I couldn't find my Ubuntu installer. But I have noted these steps for future reference.

Comment: When u say apt-get install, does it need live internet connection to the PC to get the package?

Comment: @goldenmean: one of the comments mentions it is required, so I'd say yes